# consumed bytes for php_user_filter::filter

Tags: php, php-stream-wrappers

According to http://php.net/manual/en/php-user-filter.filter.php "**consumed**, which must *always* be declared by reference, should be incremented by the length of the data which your filter reads in and alters. In most cases this means you will increment **consumed** by *$bucket->datalen* for each *$bucket.*"

So let's say you have a block cipher with a block size of 16 and you have input of length 25. At this point what you write to `$bucket->data` might be 16 bytes long despite the input being 25 bytes long. So should `$consumed` by 16 or 25?

And similarly, if you have input of length 5 you'd probably want to return `PSFS_FEED_ME` so should `$consumed` be 0 or 5?

Comment: I really would like to know this to. In my tests, it didn't make any difference no mater to wat I set $consumed. Even random numbers, strings or to simply not do any thing whit it produced the correct output....